# Fetch value from another table inside this query

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is working good, but the issue is I need to get the room number which is in another table called `rooms`. The query below fetched data from `reservations` table which only has `room_id`:

```
$select_table = "SELECT id, name, phone, email, address, country, adults, childs, purpose, booking_type, remarks, checkin, checkout, room_id, status, paid, date FROM reservations WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '$date' ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $db->prepare($select_table);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($rows)
{
getcsv(array_keys($rows));
}
while($rows)
{
getcsv($rows);
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

How on earth can I get the column `number` inside the above query from the `rooms` table?

Comment: what are the columns in the table `rooms`?

Comment: they are as follows

  id,name, number, rate,,capacity, status

in reservations table column room_id is reffered to id from rooms table

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using prepared statements and supply any user data as separate arguments because you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Join` the rooms table!

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.phone, r.email, r.address, r.country, r.adults, r.childs, r.purpose,
       r.booking_type, r.remarks, r.checkin, r.checkout, r.room_id, r.status, r.paid, r.date,
       rooms.number  
FROM reservations r
JOIN rooms ON r.room_id = rooms.id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(r.date, '%Y-%m') = '$date'
ORDER BY r.id DESC
```

(I got tired of typing `reservations` over and over again, so I create a table alias `r` for that table.)

Comment: i get blank data mate

Comment: Which you didn't get before?

Comment: both the tables all i get is blank data im actually download it as csv table and i get blank data nothing being fetch

Comment: You have some other problem then. Are you sure there are any valid rooms for your reservations? You could try LEFT JOIN instead of just (inner) join.

Comment: Was it the LEFT JOIN which did it, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to include the room number by joining the two tables:

```
  $query =  "SELECT id, name, phone, email, address, country, adults, childs, purpose, booking_type, remarks, checkin, checkout, room_id, status, paid, date , ro.number AS number FROM reservations AS r JOIN rooms AS ro ON r.room_id=ro.id WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '$date' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Assuming that the `rooms` table has an `id` field and that `reservation.room_id` is a foreign key referencing `rooms.id` the query will work.

Comment: Include your database tables' structure in your original post

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
    SELECT rooms.number, reservations.id, name, phone, email, address, country, 
    adults, childs, purpose, booking_type, remarks, checkin, checkout, room_id, 
    status, paid, date FROM reservations left join rooms on reservations. room_id =rooms.id 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '$date' ORDER BY id DESC
```